# What is the difference between kubuntu-desktop, plasma-desktop and kde-plasma-desktop packages?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I see they differ in size.

`plasma-desktop` is a dependency of `kde-plasma-desktop` and it seems that `kubuntu-desktop` and `kde-plasma-desktop` are independent of each other.

What are other differences between kubuntu-desktop, plasma-desktop and kde-plasma-desktop packages?

Comment: For those hitting this and installing with modern KDE, the best approach is to install `kde-standard` package as it will give a properly functioning KDE. `kde-plasma-desktop` is missing all kinds of stuff including icons and widgets (eg quicklaunch).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is the difference between kubuntu-desktop, plasma-desktop and
>   kde-plasma-desktop packages?

Running `apt show` on each:

- kubuntu-desktop

  - Description: Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system
- kde-plasma-desktop

  - Description: KDE Plasma Desktop and minimal set of applications
- plasma-desktop

  - Description: Tools and widgets for the desktop

Look at the *depends* for each in the output of each `apt show` command to know more.

In brief, *kubuntu-desktop* provides a fuller KDE Plasma desktop experience relative to that obtained by installing *kde-plasma-desktop*.

It's a bit like installing *xubuntu-desktop* versus *xfce4*.

---

By the way, *kubuntu-full* provides even more packages than *kubuntu-desktop*.

---

I don't know the basis for the question, but I prefer not mixing desktop environments. Other users seem to handle multiple desktop environments just fine.